# SQL Query - Select highest column value for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have the following table:

```
ProductID, GroupID, Description
1          100      Blah blah
2          200      Blah blah
3          100      Blah blah
4          200      Blah blah
5          200      Blah blah
6          100      Blah blah
7          300      Blah blah
9          300      Blah blah
10         100      Blah blah
```

I need to run a query that gets the data for this table such that EACH GroupID is retrieved exactly once, and the top-most ProductID is chosen. Example is shown below

```
ProductID, GroupID, Description
10         100      Blah blah
5          200      Blah blah
9          300      Blah blah
```

Any thoughts on the best approach for this? The goal being that each time this query is run, it always gets the latest ProductID for each particular GroupID. There are a lot more fields in this table, but I'm simplifying it to this example which essentially illustrates the main problem I'm trying to solve

Thanks!

Comment: Please see below answer, first i am down voted bcoz i cann't understand your question.Now answer edited and make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (<s>not tested</s>) :

```
SELECT t.ProductID, t.GroupID, t.Description
FROM MyTableName t
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(ProductID) As ProductID, GroupID
        FROM MyTableName
        GROUP BY GroupID) as maxPerGroup
    ON maxPerGroup.ProductID = t.ProductID
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9783/3)

Comment: explain the downvote. the query is working fine in my understanding of the question.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. it's working fine.

If someone is downvoted it. then it's not good.

To downvote anything you must have a valid reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the OVER clause to partition the table by GroupId.  This will get you a table with two columns, the productId and a rowNum.  rowNum will be 1 for the highest ProductID in each GroupID.  Next, you simply inner join to that table and get ProductIDs that have a rowNum of 1.  More info on the OVER clause can be [found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

```
SELECT yt1.*  
FROM yourTable yt1 
INNER JOIN  ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ProductId DESC) as rowNum
    , ProductID FROM yourTable 
    )yt2 
ON yt1.ProductID = yt2.ProductID 
WHERE yt2.rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For tasks such as this one, I always love using [Ranking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx):

```
SELECT ProductID, GroupID, Description FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.ProductID
        ,t.GroupID
        ,t.Description    
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.GroupID ORDER BY t.ProductID DESC) [Rank]
    FROM MyTableName t

) RawData
WHERE RANK = 1
```

In general, the inner query just gives ranks for each row in the context of it's `GroupID`
(this is done by `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.GroupID ORDER BY t.ProductID DESC`).

The wrapping query is just for filtering rows which have a rank of 1 i.e. where the `productID` is highest in the context of the specific `GroupID`.

You can view the results in this [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9783/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

select * from products;

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| productId | groupId | description |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
|         1 |     100 | hello       |
|         2 |     200 | hello       |
|         3 |     100 | hello       |
|         4 |     200 | hello       |
|         5 |     200 | hello       |
|         6 |     100 | hello       |
|         7 |     300 | hello       |
|         8 |     300 | hello       |
|         9 |     100 | hello       |
|        10 |     200 | hello       |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

select * from products where productId in (select MAX(productId) from products group by groupId) order by groupId ASC;

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+
| productId | groupId | description |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
|         9 |     100 | hello       |
|        10 |     200 | hello       |
|         8 |     300 | hello       |
+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry first i cann't understand your question,so i am down Voted.  Following is the edited correct and tested query.

your records:

```
select * from dbo.[Products]
```

[image]

Showing Distinct GroupID with top ProductID

```
;with cteProducts(ProductID , GroupID) AS
(
 select max(ProductID) ProductID , GroupID
 FROM dbo.Products od
 Group by GroupID 
)
SELECT p1.ProductID,p1.GroupID,p1.[Description] from Products p1
INNER JOIN cteProducts p2 on p1.ProductID=p2.ProductID
order by p1.ProductID Desc
```

Your required result executed here:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL, this works. Please check in SQL Server -

```
 select t.productid, t.groupid, t.description from t, (select max(productid) mp , groupid from t  group by groupid) x where t.productid=x.mp;
;
 productid | groupid | description 
-----------+---------+-------------
         5 |     200 | BLAH BLAH
         9 |     300 | BLAH BLAH
        10 |     100 | BLAH BLAH
(3 rows)
```